# Where did the ssh client go in ddev v1.3.0?

Tags: ddev

I use ssh inside the ddev web container, and it was there just fine until ddev v1.3.0. Where did it go and how do I get it back?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the base container used for the web container dropped the openssh-client Debian package in this upgrade and we didn't catch that. It will be fixed in v1.4.0 or sooner (November 2018)

In the meantime, you can:

- (easiest and fastest): Add `webimage: drud/ddev-webserver:20181017_add_ssh` to your .ddev/config.yaml (don't forget to remove it next time you upgrade)
  or
- Add these post-start steps to your .ddev/config.yaml:

```html
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: sudo bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-client || true"
```

We do apologize for losing the openssh-client package in this release.

Comment: This is fixed in our upcoming release this week, v1.4.0, aimed at Nov 14, 2018.